# How to write OOP JS and use jQuery at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Usually (if not always), when jQuery allows you to add a callback to some JS event like click, in the callback function they change the "meaning" of `this` into the DOM element which triggered the event.

This can be quite useful, but it will stand in your way when you write OOP code in js, [like in this example](http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ban/):

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype = {

    init: function() {
        $("#someSpan").click(this.doSomething);
    },

    doSomething: function() {
        alert("Here 1");
        this.test();
        return false;
    },

    test: function() {
        alert("Here 2");
    }
}
```

In this example, `this.test()` will not work, because `this` is not anymore an instance on `MyClass` but instead a jQuery DOM element (the span).

My questions are: is there a way to continue writing OOP code in JS using this pattern and also use jQuery? And: why is jQuery changing `this` in the callback function when it could as easily send the jQuery DOM element as first argument ?

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/p4Ban/1/ Also jQuery sends the DOM element via `e.currentTarget` where `e` is the event object sent as first argument

Comment: jQuery is not changing anything. Whenever you bind event handlers, `this` refers to the DOM element (unfortunately not in IE's `attachEvent`). This has nothing to do with jQuery (although of course jQuery enforces it so that it works in IE). See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get reference to parent object/class from event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656119/javascript-get-reference-to-parent-object-class-from-event-handler) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+object+method+as+event+handler+reference+this).

Comment: @Esailija Thank you, that really helps! It's not the most straightforward approach, but it works with minimal re-write.

Comment: @NicolaeSurdu yeah there is no language support for it so you must emulate static binding with all this `$.proxy/Function#bind` boilerplate crap

Comment: @Esailija: `func.bind(this)` is a language feature though.

Comment: @FelixKling I didn't knew this, obviously. Thanks a lot! It makes more sense now :)

Comment: @FelixKling I meant more of a syntactic support that would make it a lot easier, for this use case `func.bind` is not a real feature and can easily be replaced with a user-made function such as $.proxy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery has [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) that can be used like so:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.clicked = $.proxy(this.clicked, this);
}

MyClass.prototype = {

    clicked: function(e) {
        alert("Here 1");
        this.test();
        e.currentTarget; //this replaces "this"-the keyword used in "non OOP" contexts
//see http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/
    },

    init: function() {
        $("#someSpan").click(this.clicked);
    },

    test: function() {
        alert("Here 2");
    }
}
```

When you create an instance, that instance gets its own `.clicked` function that shadows the generic one in the prototype. It will
always have same `this` binding no matter how you call it. So you can pass `this.clicked` all over the place and have it work.