# Access an instance of a class from an event listener of one of the class components in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, listener, event-listener

I am seeking a way to access the **instance** of an object from within the event listener of **one of its components**.

```
function FormField() {

    this.variable = "initial";

    this.container = new Container();
    this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {

         // this.variable = "modified";
    });
}
```

I.e. a mousedown on the container will be able to identify which instance of the class the container belongs to and use this instance in its method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get reference to parent object/class from event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656119/javascript-get-reference-to-parent-object-class-from-event-handler)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new variable which references the instance directly, like this:

```
this.container = new Container();
var self = this;
this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
     console.log(self);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store this context to local var self:

```
    function FormField() {
    var self = this;
    self.variable = "initial";

    this.container = new Container();
    this.container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {

         // self.variable = "modified";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `this` to some other variable, then access it in the event handler, i.e.

```
function FormField() {
    var self = this;

    self.variable = "initial";

    self.container = new Container();
    self.container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
         // use self.variable = "modified";
    });
}
```